# Remove duplicate list object value from another object list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two object list, which have name as duplicate in both list. I need to remove all the duplicate value from list1 from list2.

Below is the scenario,
class have name variable, with this variable need to check duplicate value from list1 and need to remove.

```
Class ObjectClass{
          String name;
    }
```

//this is first list have 3 objects

```
    List<ObjectClass> list1= new ArrayList();
    ObjectClass objectClassDataL1= new ObjectClass();
    objectClassDataL1.setName("test");
    list1.add(objectClassDataL1);
    ObjectClass objectClassDataL2= new ObjectClass();
    objectClassDataL2.setName("test2");
    list1.add(objectClassDataL2);
    ObjectClass objectClassDataL3= new ObjectClass();
    objectClassDataL3.setName("test3");
    list1.add(objectClassDataL3);
    


    List<ObjectClass> list2= new ArrayList();
    
    ObjectClass objectClassData1= new ObjectClass();
    objectClassData1.setName("test");
    list2.add(objectClassData1);
    ObjectClass objectClassData2= new ObjectClass();
    objectClassData2.setName("test3");
    list2.add(objectClassData2);
```

I need to remove in list1 objects with the `name` value as in list2.
For example here after removing the data from list1, list1 should contain only one object data.
Expected output:

> list1 --> [Object('test2')]
>
> list1 size is 1

Please suggest me in Java 8 with streams.

Comment: if you override the `equals` methods you can use `removeAll()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please suggest me in JAVA 8 with stream,

Here you don't want to use stream as you want to modify the existing `list1`.
What you can do is adding the names of `list2` elements in a `Set` and removing elements from `list1` that are not contained in the `Set` :

```
Set<String> namesInList2 = list2.stream().map(ObjectClass::getName).collect(toSet());
list1.removeIf(o -> namesInList2.contains(o.getName());
```

It makes things in two steps but it is clear and efficient enough.

Comment: i have 20,000 records in both list, this will works better performance. right? And this code is works better for my scenario. Thanks

Comment: 20.000 records is not small but not huge either. Here it should be fine. Actually `Collectors.toSet()` returns an `HashSet` which provides a good performance for lookup (that is constant time) but that is also an implementation detail (while that should probably not change) . If  you want to force the implementation used for the Set you can use :  `Collections.toCollection(HashSet::new)`. It seems a little bit "too much" but well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) as:

```
list1.removeIf(a -> list2.stream().anyMatch(b -> a.getName().equals(b.getName())));
```

Comment: maybe should convert `list1` to `Set<String>` to improve performance?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin yes good idea.. create a `Set<String>`  from the `list2` and perform `contains`.

Comment: yea, ofc `list2` :)

Comment: If i have 20,000 records in both list. this is effective one? ANd this code is work fine for my scenario. thanks :-)

Comment: maybe just `list1.removeIf(a -> list2.contains(a));?`

Comment: @dehasi not really, its the comparison of names and not the object altogether.